# How can I add a note to user programmaticaly in joomla 2.5?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

How can I add a note to user programmaticaly in joomla 2.5?

(Sorry, I can't post images but I mean this section in joomla - https://monosnap.com/image/ZosdVDrdP8CwBTintksUmH7EwDXe9Q )

Comment: @Lodder I've tried to look in official API, tried to google the question, but there is no information at all.

Comment: The user note table is just a table, you need to make an instance, add the data from where ever you are getting it, and store it.  I don't think it's substantively different than programmatically creating any other data which is why you are not going to find docs specifically about it.

Comment: @Elin Thank you! I will make a simple insert.

Comment: Close the question if you got the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by simple sql insert to the table user_note.